Calculate marginal effects with fixest class model
I want to manually calculate the marginal effects of an interaction term at different specific values of a third variable. I am working with a fixest class model.
Let´s assume this is my model
data(mtcars)

m1 <- feols(mpg ~ vs*disp + drat | am, data= mtcars)


I want to calculate the AME vs, disp, and the standalone interaction term vs*disp at four values of drat: 3, 3.5 and 4
Note that I want the p-value along the point estimate.
Thank you

I would check out the vignettes for marginaleffects . The package author goes through several examples with interaction terms.Interflex is also another fantastic option for getting the marginal effects of an interaction term
